# Godot, GDScript - Play Animation on Right Click

Tags: godot, gdscript

Any insight onto why this code doesn't work?

When I right click, the game crashes and gives the error: "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'play' in base 'Array'".

```
   func _ready():
       anim_Play = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("AnimationPlayer")
```

```
   func_input(event):
      if Input.is_action_pressed("aim"):
        anim_Play.play("AimSights")
```

Comment: Forgot to add that I do have an 'anim_Play' variable equal to null.

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful; there are many ways something doesn't work: It plays the wrong animation, it throws an exception, nothing happens, it plays half the animation, etc. Define your intent with the code and actual behaviour.

Comment: When I right click it crashes the game and gives the error: "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'play' in base 'Array'.

Comment: I recommend checking the node structure created when game is running, then traverse the tree appropriately in code to find "AnimationPlayer". Seems like what you are getting back from `get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("AnimationPlayer")` is not the actual `AnimationPlayer` since it can't find `play()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your code that you are trying to get a reference to your `AnimationPlayer` node, it fails and you get an Array instead.

It happens because you are using [`get_nodes_in_group`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-method-get-nodes-in-group) (which returns an Array of nodes in a group), instead of `get_node`, which returns a node.

> Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'play' in base 'Array

Means your are trying the call the `play` method (found in AnimationPlayer) from an Array object, that does not exist.

You would get `AnimationPlayer` like

```
var anim_Play = get_node("./path/to/your/AnimationPlayer")
```

Comment: I still get the error "Node not found: AnimationPlayer" and even get a new error: "Attempt to call function 'play' in base 'null instance' on a null instance."

Comment: did you rename it? you can use the editor to look it up, e.g. `var anim = $path/to/player`

Answer (score 0):

## Response to your question

`get_nodes_in_group(group)` returns an `Array` of nodes that are both in the `SceneTree` and in group `group`.

Let's say there is one AnimationPlayer node in the group "AnimationPlayer". We'll fetch it like:

```
var anim_player = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("AnimationPlayer")[0]
```

Notice the `[0]`. That is called an accessor. We access the array at element `0`. Now, we can call play:

```
anim_player.play("AimSights")
```

Do note: it is an error to access a non-existent element of an array.

## Recommendation

This seems like an inappropriate use of groups. I recommend you use a node path, like svarog suggested, if the animation player is in the same scene as the script.

Additionally, it will help to read or google about some fundamental programming concepts: specifically Objects and Arrays.

Lastly, read over the scenes and nodes page from Godot's documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/scenes_and_nodes.html

The whole getting started guide on the Godot's documentation is an invaluable resource for learning Godot. It will help you greatly and it's not too long of a read.

Good luck!